# Objective C - Webkit external files causing 401

Tags: objective-c, webkit

I'm currently using Webkit to display a mobile web on my iPhone app.
The domain is password protected, so I pass the username & password to the request.

It loads the main HTML page fine, however, even after passing the username & password, any other pages that the main HTML page loads (i.e css and js) are all returning 401.

Is there a way around that?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the use cases for [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIWebPageRequest-a-new-class-for-downloading-complete-webpages).

If you want something lower level, you'll have to create an [NSURLCredential](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredential_Class/) instance and an [NSURLProtectionSpace](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtectionSpace_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLProtectionSpace) and save them to the [credential store](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCredentialStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLCredentialStorage/setCredential%3aforProtectionSpace%3a). At this point, the UIWebView should use the credential for all requests that match the protection space (which basically represents your site).

---

Here's some sample code, taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html), which is not really where I'd expect to find it.

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc]
                        initWithUser: @"userName"
                            password: @"password"
                         persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                            initWithHost: @"www.mydomain.com"
                                    port: 80
                                protocol: @"http"
                                   realm: @"mydomain.com"
                    authenticationMethod: NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];


[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage]
                    setDefaultCredential: credential
                      forProtectionSpace: protectionSpace];

[credential release];
[protectionSpace release];
```

Comment: FYI, missing a ';' at the end of your NSURLCrendentialStorage call.

Comment: Also missing a '@' in your initWithHost parameter. :)

Comment: Thanks. I've fixred them both.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to pass the username and password in the css and js includes also...