# How do I detect an authentication challenge from a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, http-authentication, uiwebviewdelegate

I've seen [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818120/how-to-implement-ntlm-authentication-for-uiwebview?lq=1) that ask (and answer) how to supply credentials when you know beforehand that the request requires them.

When I load a site that requests an authentication challenge, (responds with HTTP 401), my `UIWebViewDelegate` only receives the following callbacks: `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and sometimes `webViewDidStartLoad:` (`webViewDidStartLoad:` seems to be called if I navigate directly to the site, and it seems not to be called if I'm redirected there).

By overriding `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:]`, the `UIWebViewDelegate` receives some calls to `uiWebView:resource:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:forDataSource:` and `uiWebView:resource:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:fromDataSource:`, which could be useful, but of course those are private API and will probably get my app rejected.

I've tested a few different mainstream apps with embedded `UIWebView`s. So far, only Chrome handles these authentication challenges properly. I've even set up my own server and validated that Chrome only `POST`s once. Twitter and Tweetbot fail just show the loading screen forever, just like mine.

Is there another (probably very hacky) way to detect these authentication challenges other than using a second speculative `NSURLConnection`? If I make a `POST` request, that will double-`POST` everything, which is bad.

[I've added a radar to request an enhancement to UIWebView for this](http://openradar.appspot.com/13748318). Please duplicate it.

Comment: Thanks for making the radar request - I've duped it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apple now has sample code that solves this problem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Listings/Read_Me_About_CustomHTTPProtocol_txt.html). It also looks like the most complete documentation of how to implement an NSURLProtocol properly.

Comment: I'm having issues with this sample code. One of my NSURLConnections stops receiving callbacks. However, this still seems to be the best option out there. I've filed a TSI with DTS, and hopefully Apple can help me resolve my issue.

Comment: My issue happened because I had another `NSURLProtocol` that used an `NSURLConnection`, which was intercepting `UIWebView` calls. After talking to Apple DTS, it sounds like you can't use `NSURLConnection`-based `NSURLProtocol`s with `UIWebView`. Apple's sample code uses `NSURLSession` so it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

You could load all requests in your own `NSURLConnection`, then feed the data into the webview as a string. This would allow you to intercept the connection in all its glory and still get the native `UIWebView` rendering. I’m not sure if it would work well with streaming the data into the web view as it arrives, but hopefully we aren’t talking about too much data here.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I'm doing now.

Comment: I’d be interested to hear, either here or on Twitter, how it works out, especially if you try incrementally loading the HTML string.

Comment: I'm not planning to do incremental loading. I'll try to blog about this once I get it going.

Comment: This method doesn't work if the page does XHR or uses iframes. I've rewritten the system to use an NSURLProtocol, which seems to handle that case ok.

Comment: I just found some Apple sample code that solves this problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18965789/9636